# Block application from accessing the internet on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

how can I block an application from accessing the internet on ubuntu. 
I do not want a GUI solution.

Comment: Question unclear. About what kind of application are you talking about and why do you want to block it to access internet?

Comment: It is a c++ application and I want to protect my privacy.

Comment: Dup of https://askubuntu.com/questions/45072/how-to-control-internet-access-for-each-program

Answer (score 0):

Question is clear and relevant. User installs a password manager that works great but chats with dev server. Can this app leak passwords to the web? It might do so on purpose (to sell a list of alive passwords) or due to a bug (think of a HeartBleed). Prevent an app from going to the WAN is a valid strategy.

How to implement this?

(1) Router firewall or an ad-hoc network that only permits connection to a dedicated gatekeeper server. Add a simple API like a two step SSL encryption of data to add security through obscurity. Gatekeeper's only need to forward sensitive data, so the workload can be small and a PC from 2000x would be enough. Router assigns 192.168.1.220 while gateway only serves IPs up to 200. This is simple and robust.

(2) No-internet group ( see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1188099&s=73e8a8809da60f5e49641129388c7658  ). Works as an additional layer of security only.

```
$ run_command
Linux: You don't look cool enough, why should I serve you?
$ sudo run_command
Linux: ok, fine. Let me spit an obscured error message. Go fix the mess
$ browser ->  Google search -> "I got this error message" //and then
$ wget -O NoNameRepo.com/an_app/install_me_I_will_not_harm_you_hehe.tar.gz
```

We got used to grant root privileges to apps recommended by a stranger on some forum. Once no-internet app gets root privileges it can check which groups it belongs to and remove itself from no-internet users.

Same is true for immunodeficient Windows. Additionally, malicious process can execute it's code using credentials of a trusted process. Firewall and antivirus can only protect from basic threats.

(3) Running process on a virtual guest is another unreliable option. Rights elevation defeats Sandboxy. VBox and VMWare are more reliable, but are still vulnerable. Version changelog has a lot of records saying "patch fixed another security related bug".